# How to send multiple messages in Zen-Cart using zen_mail?

Tags: php, zen-cart

I'm trying to invoke zen_mail twice so that I can send an email to myself (admin) and my customer. I'm using the following to invoke it but I cannot seem to get it to work. When I do call it, it causes the emails not to send out. Can anyone help?

```
  zen_mail($customer['customers_firstname'] . " " . $customer['customers_lastname'],
       $admin,
       $subject,
       $text,
       TITLE,
       $admin['admin_email'],
       $block,
       $module_used
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages to multiple recipients using zen_mail but the syntax is screwy.  Why not just call zen_mail twice - once for the customer and once for the admin.  This is the technique that is used in

```
includes/classes/orders.php
```

you can search for zen_mail in this file and find the calls.

Comment: Small problem. When I do this, use zen_mail twice, Zen-Cart always spits back an error saying that Zen-Cart was unable to send the message. I'll try it again though.

Answer (score 0):

In the ZENCART admin:

Configuration->Email Options:
  Send Copy of Order Confirmation Emails To:

Here you can place multiple email addresses: ME,Joe,Fred

This will send confirmation emails to ME, Joe and Fred in addition to your customer.